# how to merge two lists in inside a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a function that accepts a datatable:

```
create.p <- function(data_F){
   
    p.ad <- lapply(strsplit(data_F, " "), function(x) p.adjust(as.numeric(x)))
    data_F<- lapply(strsplit(data_F, " "), function(x) as.numeric(x))
    rez <- paste(data_F,p.ad)
    return(rez)

}
```

`p.ad`-traverses the entire data frame, translates to num, and calculates p. adjust.

`data_F`-passes through the entire data frame, translates to num.

`rez`-combining these two lists.

My problem is that the lists don't want to merge. How do I fix this?

I suspect it's the structure

```
$ rez    : chr  "c(1,0.06,0.07) c(1.00 0.18 0.18)"
```

What I expect:

```
paste(data_F,p.ad)
#"1,0-1.00"
#"0.06-0.18"
#"0.07-0.18"
```

But when I merge, nothing changes

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @sorifiend I would like to make a union inside the function to open it later in data. table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
create.p <- function(data_F){
  
  p.ad <- lapply(strsplit(data_F, " "), function(x) p.adjust(as.numeric(x)))
  data_F<- lapply(strsplit(data_F, " "), function(x) as.numeric(x))
  rez <- paste0(unlist(data_F),'-',unlist(p.ad))
  return(rez)
  
}
```

Comment: yes, it worked for me, it prints each value in a new column, how do I make it count in one? I'm trying to use lapply `rez <- c(unlist(data_F),unlist(p.ad))
    rez <- lapply(rez,paste0)` but it didn't help

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, but let me try to answer. I assume that you want to merge the output of `create.p`. Try to use `paste(create.p(data_F),collapse = ' # ')`

Comment: not really, it records one result in each column.